# Modificar una variable desde el server con Socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Necesito cambiar unas variables de un *script* de la vista de mi proyecto, pero necesito hacerlo desde el servidor o hacer que la variable tome el valor que le mando a través de *websockets*.

Yo intenté lo siguiente:

```
//EN EL SERVER

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){

    socket.emit("NombreDelSocket",UnDatoJSON);
});


//EN EL CLIENTE

var Nombre;

var socket = io.connect(RUTA DEL SERVIDOR);

socket.on("NombreDelSocket",function(data){

   //data es UnDatoJSON que mando el servidor
    Nombre = data[0].nombre; 
    console.log(Nombre);
});
```

Cuando yo chequeo la consola del navegador, efectivamente la instrucción `console.log(Nombre)`, me imprime el nombre que quise mandar. Muy bien, pero no me modifica el nombre de la variable. Si yo ese mensaje de la consola lo muestro afuera de ese método del `socket`, me dirá que el nombre es `undefined`.

No se si comprenden lo que quiero hacer. Simplemente quiero setear una variable de un script del cliente, pero no se como hacerlo desde *websockets*.

Answer (score 2):

La función que se pasa al método `socket.on("NombreDelSocket"` es ejecutada en algún momento en el tiempo debido a que es un evento asincronico.

> Si yo ese mensaje de la consola lo muestro afuera de ese metodo del socket me dira que el nombre es undefined.

Ya que no has inicializado la variable `Nombre` el valor es `undefined`. El error radica en que intentas logear el valor de la variable `Nombre` cuando todavía el evento `NombreDelSocket` no se ejecuto.

> cuando yo chequeo la consola del navegador, efectivamente la instrucción console.log(Nombre) me imprime el nombre que quise mandar, muy bien, pero no me modificar el nombre de la Variable.

El valor de la variable `Nombre` si se modifica, solo que no inmediatamente, debes esperar a que el evento `NombreDelSocket` sea ejecutado.

Una posible solución seria invocar una función para notificar que `Nombre` fue modificado.

Por ejemplo:

```
//EN EL CLIENTE
var Nombre;
var socket = io.connect(RUTA DEL SERVIDOR);
socket.on("NombreDelSocket",function(data){

   //data es UnDatoJSON que mando el servidor
    Nombre = data[0].nombre; 
    avisarQueNombreFueSeteado();
});
function avisarQueNombreFueSeteado() {
   console.log(Nombre);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Y como hago para que sea directo ?

Comment: Por que habrías de querer hacer eso? Considera que: `Node.js usa un modelo de operaciones E/S sin bloqueo y orientado a eventos`. Y por lo poco que muestras en tu codigo, `UnDatoJSON` seguramente es algo cargado asincronicamente, y por lo tanto no lo veo posible

Comment: Porque necesito meter datos en esos valores de variables en un script del cliente para que se vean su cambio en la vista. Pensé que el uso de websockets me resolvería el problema porque son conexiones entre el cliente y sevidor. Y al parecer me metí en otro problema

Comment: Si puedes proveer la `RUTA DEL SERVIDOR`, puedo intentar ayudarte a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion posible a tu problema es modificar directamente el elemento html con el valor del nombre recibido desde el servidor.

Por ejemplo, si lo que tienes es un <p id="myP"> y quieres que tenga el nombre de la persona, lo que puedes hacer es, sustituir console.log(Nombre) por document.myP.innerHTML = Nombre, o usando jQuery $('#myP').text(Nombre). Debes tener en cuenta que cuando ese evento se dispare, es que puedes mostrar los datos que quieres al usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se puede hacer es realizar un refresco de vista, pero eso depende de como estes trabajando la modificacion de las vistas, ejemplo si es jquery tocaria hacer una actualizacion del tag donde este la variable o si es angular, seria actualizar una variable del scope, de forma que cuando llegue la señal de socket io, se ejecute la funcion sugerida en la respuesta inmediatamente anterior y se invocaria el cambio en el dom o el refresco del scope

Answer (score 0):

Veo que lo que necesitas hacer es modificar "algo" usando el valor que viene del servidor.
Debes tener en cuenta que el evento `NombreDelSocket` se ejecuta cuando se establece la conexión y eso sucede muy seguramente despues de que todo tu javascript se cargó y ejecutó, por eso la variable `Nombre` esta vacia inicialmente..

en complemento con la respuesta de @marcos, quiero agregar:
la solución entonces es sencilla, debes aplicar los cambios cuando el evento es llamado, algo asi:

```
//EN EL CLIENTE

var Nombre;

var socket = io.connect(RUTA DEL SERVIDOR);

socket.on("NombreDelSocket",function(data){

   //data es UnDatoJSON que mando el servidor
    Nombre = data[0].nombre; 
    console.log(Nombre);
   // en este instante tu variable que tiene "algo" asi que puedes usarla.
    modificaAlgo();
    });

// funcion que utiliza la variable nombre, para hacer algo!
   function modificaAlgo(){
     // aqui escribes las instrucciones y puedes usar la variable Nombre que ya tiene algún valor.
   }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Deber usar el callback:

```
var Nombre;

var socket = io.connect(RUTA DEL SERVIDOR);

socket.on("NombreDelSocket",function(data){

    actualizarVariable(data);
});

function actualizarVariable(data){
     //data es UnDatoJSON que mando el servidor
    Nombre = data[0].nombre; 
}
```